# can we use ColorPicker Ajax Control in asp 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, .net-2.0, controls, color-picker

Use of ColorPickerExtender in **asp 2.0**

Provide Example

Comment: What else do you need?  http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ColorPicker/ColorPicker.aspx

Comment: @Gabriel- Please Refer the Question Perfectly, i want to use ColorPickerExtender in ASP **2.0** Not in asp **3.5**, ColorpickerControl is Provided in Later version of AJAX

Comment: Author wants to use colorpicker in 2.0 as he had specified in the question.

Comment: Thank you.  I misread the question.  Now that I have read it correctly, I have a new comment.  Why aren't you using v3.5?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should go for new ASP.NET Ajax Library, still Beta but very good one...

And no need to worry about ASP.NET Version

check this out
[HOW TO Use the ColorPicker Control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20ColorPicker%20Control.ashx)

[ASP.NET Ajax Library](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/MainPage.ashx)

Cheers!!!